# Check time reached automatically in backend node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, backend

I am using node js and mysql for my backend and the project is about book shifts. I am new in backend so what I want to know how to handle if the shift time comes so the shift will cancel or extended.. whatever.

I just want to know how this can be done? to make the backend check automatically when the time is reached so the shift will cancel, extended whatever.

I want to know the concept name. or any article or library.. whatever?

Comment: you can use backend job at regular interval

Comment: sorry can you explain?